# How to set ImageView align to parent bottom and scaleType

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, android-wrap-content

I'm trying to align an image to it's parents bottom. The basic idea is to fit the image to screen width, use `wrap_content` for height and then align all that to the parent's bottom. Unfortunately the result is a 1-2dp margin at the bottom I cannot get rid of. I changed the parent's background here to blue so it is obvious:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/top_graphic" />
//...
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks like in layout builder:

[image]

That blue line at the bottom I cannot get rid of. I don't want to use direct `dp` values obviously, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/top_graphic" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately same result. Only thing worked so far is setting negative margin